# How can I disable previous checkbox and next checkbox in a loop using jquery?

Tags: jquery, html

How can I disable the previous checkbox and the next checkbox in a loop using jquery? Right Now I am disabling "this" to disable current checkbox but I would also like to disable the previous checkbox and the next checkbox as well.

```
var CurrentCoordinationTimesArray, CurrentAvailableTimesArray;

for (var i = 0; i < gAssessorEventsArray.length; i++) {
    if (gAssessorEventsArray[i].EventID == ev.EventID) {
        CurrentCoordinationTimesArray = gAssessorEventsArray[i].CoordinationTimes.split(';');
        alert(CurrentCoordinationTimesArray);

        for (var j = 0; j < CurrentCoordinationTimesArray.length; j++) {
            alert(CurrentCoordinationTimesArray[j]);
            $('#AvailableTimesTable input[type=checkbox]').each(function () {
                if ($(this).val() == (CurrentCoordinationTimesArray[j] + ';')) this.disabled = 'true';
            });
        }

        break;
    }
}
```

This is my HTML:

```
<table width="620px" cellspacing="5" id="AvailableTimesTable" style="margin-top: 5px;border: 1px solid black; background-color: #E2EFFF;">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="LightBoxHeadingCell" colspan="4">Available Times :</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="color:green;" class="AvailableTimes">
                <input type="checkbox" value="08:00 AM - 09:00 AM;" name="AvailableTimesCheckboxes" disabled="">08:00 AM - 09:00 AM</td>
            <td style="color:blue;" class="AvailableTimes">
                <input type="checkbox" value="08:30 AM - 09:30 AM;" name="AvailableTimesCheckboxes">08:30 AM - 09:30 AM</td>
            <td style="color:green;" class="AvailableTimes">
                <input type="checkbox" value="09:00 AM - 10:00 AM;" name="AvailableTimesCheckboxes">09:00 AM - 10:00 AM</td>
            <td style="color:blue;" class="AvailableTimes">
                <input type="checkbox" value="09:30 AM - 10:30 AM;" name="AvailableTimesCheckboxes">09:30 AM - 10:30 AM</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="color:green;" class="AvailableTimes">
                <input type="checkbox" value="10:00 AM - 11:00 AM;" name="AvailableTimesCheckboxes" disabled="">10:00 AM - 11:00 AM</td>
            <td style="color:blue;" class="AvailableTimes">
                <input type="checkbox" value="10:30 AM - 11:30 AM;" name="AvailableTimesCheckboxes">10:30 AM - 11:30 AM</td>
            <td style="color:green;" class="AvailableTimes">
                <input type="checkbox" value="11:00 AM - 12:00 PM;" name="AvailableTimesCheckboxes">11:00 AM - 12:00 PM</td>
            <td style="color:blue;" class="AvailableTimes">
                <input type="checkbox" value="11:30 AM - 12:30 PM;" name="AvailableTimesCheckboxes">11:30 AM - 12:30 PM</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="color:green;" class="AvailableTimes">
                <input type="checkbox" value="12:00 PM - 01:00 PM;" name="AvailableTimesCheckboxes">12:00 PM - 01:00 PM</td>
            <td style="color:blue;" class="AvailableTimes">
                <input type="checkbox" value="12:30 PM - 01:30 PM;" name="AvailableTimesCheckboxes">12:30 PM - 01:30 PM</td>
            <td style="color:green;" class="AvailableTimes">
                <input type="checkbox" value="01:00 PM - 02:00 PM;" name="AvailableTimesCheckboxes">01:00 PM - 02:00 PM</td>
            <td style="color:blue;" class="AvailableTimes">
                <input type="checkbox" value="01:30 PM - 02:30 PM;" name="AvailableTimesCheckboxes">01:30 PM - 02:30 PM</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="color:green;" class="AvailableTimes">
                <input type="checkbox" value="02:00 PM - 03:00 PM;" name="AvailableTimesCheckboxes">02:00 PM - 03:00 PM</td>
            <td style="color:blue;" class="AvailableTimes">
                <input type="checkbox" value="02:30 PM - 03:30 PM;" name="AvailableTimesCheckboxes">02:30 PM - 03:30 PM</td>
            <td style="color:green;" class="AvailableTimes">
                <input type="checkbox" value="03:00 PM - 04:00 PM;" name="AvailableTimesCheckboxes">03:00 PM - 04:00 PM</td>
            <td style="color:blue;" class="AvailableTimes">
                <input type="checkbox" value="03:30 PM - 04:30 PM;" name="AvailableTimesCheckboxes">03:30 PM - 04:30 PM</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="color:green;" class="AvailableTimes">
                <input type="checkbox" value="04:00 PM - 05:00 PM;" name="AvailableTimesCheckboxes">04:00 PM - 05:00 PM</td>
            <td style="color:blue;" class="AvailableTimes">
                <input type="checkbox" value="04:30 PM - 05:30 PM;" name="AvailableTimesCheckboxes">04:30 PM - 05:30 PM</td>
            <td style="color:green;" class="AvailableTimes">
                <input type="checkbox" value="05:00 PM - 06:00 PM;" name="AvailableTimesCheckboxes">05:00 PM - 06:00 PM</td>
            <td style="color:blue;" class="AvailableTimes">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Use jQuery methods like `.prev()` and `.next()` to find the previous and next checkboxes. The precise details depend on how you've arranged the checkboxes in the HTML, could you show that?

Comment: I just shared my HTML

Comment: what is CurrentCoordinationTimesArray ??

Comment: CurrentCoordinationTimesArray = gAssessorEventsArray[i].CoordinationTimes.split(';');  and right now it contains 08:00 AM - 09:00 AM,10:00 AM - 11:00 AM. I also update my code at the top as well.

Comment: So you have to split on the comma between those also, then disable those checkboxes that match that as well as the ones just prior and subsequent to that match?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, IF I understand your requirement, and what you want to do based on the array value is

1. disable the current time checkbox
2. disable the previous time checkbox (even if in another row)
3. disable the next time checkbox (even if in another row)

This brings some handy  traversal of your table in play.

First off, you need to disable using `$(this).prop("disabled",true);` for whatever selector you choose.  That is effectively the same as your `this.disabled = 'true';` but it is easier to do on the "other" elements that way.  That is the easy part, the real trick here is finding the prevous/next element in another row in the table.

Sample code with some assumptions on the array, but it just gets the values:

```
var gAssessorEventsArray = [{
    CoordinationTimes: "08:00 AM - 09:00 AM;10:00 AM - 11:00 AM",
    EventID: "fred"
}];
var ev = {};
ev.EventID = "fred";
for (var i = 0; i < gAssessorEventsArray.length; i++) {
    if (gAssessorEventsArray[i].EventID == ev.EventID) {
        CurrentCoordinationTimesArray = gAssessorEventsArray[i].CoordinationTimes.split(';');
        alert(CurrentCoordinationTimesArray);

        for (var j = 0; j < CurrentCoordinationTimesArray.length; j++) {
            alert(CurrentCoordinationTimesArray[j]);
            $('#AvailableTimesTable input[type=checkbox]').each(function () {
                if ($(this).val() == (CurrentCoordinationTimesArray[j] + ';')) {
                    this.disabled = 'true';
                    var myParentTd = $(this).parent();
                    var myParentTr = myParentTd.parent();
                    if (myParentTd.next().find('input[type="checkbox"]').length) {
                        myParentTd.next().find('input[type="checkbox"]').prop("disabled", true);
                    } else {
                        myParentTr.next().find('input[type="checkbox"]').first().prop("disabled", true);

                    }
                    if (myParentTd.prev().find('input[type="checkbox"]').length) {
                        myParentTd.prev().find('input[type="checkbox"]').prop("disabled", true);
                    } else {
                        myParentTr.prev().css('background-color','lime');
                        myParentTr.prev().find('td>input[type="checkbox"]').last().prop("disabled", true);

                    }
                }
            });
        }

        break;
    }
}
```

Sample working document: http://jsfiddle.net/HbRsM/

NOW just to show we can simplify this, I added a class to all the input checkboxes, then selected on that, making the code and traversal easier/simpler:  This uses the index of the element from the `.each(index,element)` to find the previous/next ones by adding and subtracting one from the current index.

```
var gAssessorEventsArray = [{
    CoordinationTimes: "08:00 AM - 09:00 AM;10:00 AM - 11:00 AM",
    EventID: "fred"
}];
var ev = {};
ev.EventID = "fred";
for (var i = 0; i < gAssessorEventsArray.length; i++) {
    if (gAssessorEventsArray[i].EventID == ev.EventID) {
        CurrentCoordinationTimesArray = gAssessorEventsArray[i].CoordinationTimes.split(';');
        alert(CurrentCoordinationTimesArray);

        for (var j = 0; j < CurrentCoordinationTimesArray.length; j++) {
            alert(CurrentCoordinationTimesArray[j]);
            var checkboxes = $('#AvailableTimesTable').find(' input[type=checkbox].AvailableTimesCheckboxes');
            checkboxes.each(function (index, element) {
                if ($(this).val() == (CurrentCoordinationTimesArray[j] + ';')) {
                    $(element).prop("disabled",true);
                    checkboxes.eq((index > 0 ? index - 1 : index)).prop("disabled", true);
                    checkboxes.eq(index+1).prop("disabled",true);
                }
            });
        }

        break;
    }
}
```

Updated fiddle for that: http://jsfiddle.net/HbRsM/1/

Comment: I am using jquery-1.4.2.min.js for a specific reason and I can't upgrade it on this application and I think prop is in 1.6.

Comment: Just change the `checkboxes.eq(index-1).prop("disabled",true);` to `checkboxes.eq(index-1)[0].disabled=true;` which selects the element, same for the next one.  If you have such requirements in the future, put that in the question.

Comment: your first solution is working, The second solution disables 05:00 PM - 06:00 PM for no reason.

Comment: I forgot about the wrap they added in vers 1.4x on negative index.  Change the  `checkboxes.eq(index-1).prop("disabled",true);` to `checkboxes.eq((index > 0 ? index - 1 : index)).prop("disabled", true);` which will simply reset the index (current) to disabled per your request anyway.

Comment: I am going with your first solution. Thank you very much. I just changed prop to attr and it works.

Answer (score 0):

This will do the trick

[.next()](http://api.jquery.com/next/) [.prev()](http://api.jquery.com/prev/) documentation

This will work if the checkbox is immediate previous or next in the DOM.

```
$(this).prev('input:checkbox').attr('disable',true);
$(this).next('input:checkbox').attr('disable',true);
```

This will work even if the checkbox is not immediate previous or next in the DOM

[.nextAll()](http://api.jquery.com/nextAll/) [prevAll](http://api.jquery.com/prevAll/) [.eq()](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) documentation

```
$(this).prevAll('input:checkbox').eq(0).attr('disable',true);
$(this).nextAll('input:checkbox').eq(0).attr('disable',true);
```

Comment: jQuery has specific method for both, **.siblings()**

Comment: There's a typo in the answer. It's "disabled", not "disable". Also, try `.prop('disabled', true)` instead of `.attr('disable', true)`, it is the correct way

Answer (score 0):

Well in your case you have

TR > TD > Checkbox

To disable the other checkboxes inside the same row, you should go to the column (TD), move to the next column and disable the checkbox inside it.

With this in mind you should:

```
// Go to next/previous TD to disable its checkboxes
$(this).closest('td').prev('td').find('input:checkbox').prop('disabled',true);
$(this).closest('td').next('td').find('input:checkbox').prop('disabled',true);
```

If you want to gain more performance, cache your parent TD in a variable

```
var jqParentTD = $(this).closest('td');
jqParentTD.prev('td').find('input:checkbox').prop('disabled',true);
jqParentTD.next('td').find('input:checkbox').prop('disabled',true);
```